# Check if directory is empty using MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

Is there a convenient way to check if a directory is empty using MSBuild?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create an item and see if it contains anything, like this:

```
<Target Name="CheckDirectoryForEmpty">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <EmptyCheck>./PathTo/DirectoryToCheck/*.*</EmptyCheck>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmptyCheck Include="$(EmptyCheck)" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Message
    Condition="'@(EmptyCheck)' == ''"
    Text="Directory '$(EmptyCheck)' is empty"
    />
</Target>
```

To check recursively, use `**/*.*` instead of `*.*` in the path.

Comment: My case was similar, but I had to check for multiple folders. If re-using the EmptyCheck ItemGroup, I had to empty it first thus: <EmptyCheck Remove=@(EmptyCheck) />. When not empty, it can be appended to a different ItemGroup using: <DifferentItemGroup Include=@(EmptyCheck) />

Answer (score 2):

You could use one of the tasks in the [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com) for this.  Use the [`FindUnder` task](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/3.5.8.0/html/b4f59b22-548f-c6c1-ee13-f6fb76411963.htm), and check whether `FoundItems` is empty.